# How to hook into Windows network events

Tags: windows, winapi

I would like to hook into certain windows network events, such as new incoming and outgoing connections.

What are the options? wmic, windows API?

Comment: WDK, you need a filter driver.  Writing and debugging your own is, erm, untrivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a look at WinPcap:
http://www.winpcap.org/

"WinPcap is an open source library for packet capture and network analysis for the Win32 platforms."
http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/main.html

This is the library that programs like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) uses to do all it's capturing with. http://www.winpcap.org/misc/features.htm

Comment: WinPcap was on my mind and is overall quite promising approach.

Comment: After searching wide and far for the "best" approach, I've settled on this. Reason being is that injecting a system level like @jonathan-lingle suggested could be too heavy on performance, not to mention the freezes if you get a NULL dereference somewhere. WinPcap with a very narrow filter hopefully won't impact performance that much while enabling to capture tcp-syn events.

Answer (score 2):

You could inject a DLL that hooks send() and recv() into every process. The DLL would then also hook CreateProcess to inject itself into processes created in the future.

Comment: I like this approach. Are there any public examples you would recommend?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, for system wide hooking of CreateProcess() we need add kernel hook right ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some tools to filter,modify,read packet in windows:

1. [WinDivert](http://reqrypt.org/divert.html) Free open source project work on Windows 7, 2008 or
   upper. network layer.
2. [WinpkFilter 3.0](http://www.ntkernel.com/w&p.php?id=7) Commercial, Windows XP and upper. datalink
   layer
3. [pcausa](http://pcausa.com/), Commercial. datalink layer
4. [Windows Filtering Platform Packet Modification Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff571070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) A sample
   to create callout driver that WinDivert use, you should now to
   implement kernel driver. network layer.